# HTML messaging system Acting weird

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite, flask

## What I'm experiencing:

> I made an HTML, JavaScript, Python(Flask) SQLite3 messaging system. And it's acting weird In Two ways.

## The first way:

> It gives infinitely the messages, an example:
>
> John: hello
>
> Bob: Hi
>
> John: hello
>
> Bob: Hi
>
> but john only said once hello and Bob said Hi once too, and it's scrolling down all the time which is making it impossible to scroll up to see other messages

## Second way:

> When I send One message, it's not letting me anymore sending other messages. I have to reload the page so I can send the messages. And it sometimes shows me the input field and send button form twice when I click the send message. Like it's duplicating itself.

## My HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome, {{ username }}!</h1>
    <div class="chat-bigger">
        <div class="chat-area">
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="msg-container {% if message[1] == username %}sender{% else %}receiver{% endif %}">
                <div class="username">{{ message[1] }}</div>
                <div class="message">{{ message[2] }}</div>
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        <form id="sendmsg-form" class="sendmsg">
            <div class="inputmsg">
                <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function longPoll() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sendmsg',
                type: 'GET',
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function(data) {
                    var newMessages = $(data).find('.chat-area').html();
                    $('.chat-area').append(newMessages);
                    $('.chat-area').scrollTop($('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight);
                    longPoll();
                },
                error: function() {
                    longPoll();
                }
            });
        }
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $('.chat-area').scrollTop($('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight);
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            longPoll();
            $('.chat-area').scrollTop($('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight);
            $('#sendmsg-form').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#sendmsg-form button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#sendmsg-form button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/sendmsg',
                    data: $('#sendmsg-form').serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#sendmsg-form button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                        $('#sendmsg-form input[name="message"]').val('');
                        var isScrolledToBottom = $('.chat-area').scrollTop() + $('.chat-area').outerHeight() >= $('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight;
                        console.log('isScrolledToBottom:', isScrolledToBottom);
                        if (isScrolledToBottom) {
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                $('.chat-area').scrollTop($('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight);
                            }, 100);
                        }
                        $('.chat-area').append(response);
                        // Scroll to the bottom of the chat area after sending a message
                        $('.chat-area').scrollTop($('.chat-area')[0].scrollHeight);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.error(`Error: ${xhr}`);
                        $('#sendmsg-form button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## My Python Code:

```py
@app.route('/sendmsg', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def sendmsg():
    if 'token' in session:
        with sqlite3.connect('users.db', check_same_thread=False) as db:
            c = db.cursor()
            token = session['token']
            c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE token=?", (token,))
            result = c.fetchone()
            if result:
                c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE token=?", (token,))
                username= c.fetchone()[0]
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    message = request.form['message']
                    if message.strip():
                        db = sqlite3.connect('chat.db', check_same_thread=False)
                        c = db.cursor()
                        c.execute("INSERT INTO messages (username, message) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, message))
                        db.commit()
                        c.execute("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
                        latest_message = c.fetchone()
                        db.close()
                        if latest_message:
                            messages = [latest_message]
                        else:
                            messages = []
                        return render_template('tempsecret.html', username=username, messages=messages)

                db = sqlite3.connect('chat.db', check_same_thread=False)
                c = db.cursor()
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY timestamp")
                messages = c.fetchall()
                db.close()
                return render_template('tempsecret.html', username=username, messages=messages)

    flash("You need to login first", "error")
    return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

## Traceback:

> No traceback because there is no error, it's maybe a problem from the way I developed the website.

Comment: my guess is your ajax call is hitting the ```/sendmsg``` route multiple times.

Comment: for which problem? I gave two.

Comment: "It gives infinitely the messages"

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right.. How can I try to fix that?

Comment: Unsure and can't test it. You are appending to ```newMessages```,  It may contain duplicates.

Comment: I think that it's maybe caused because I didn't make it check for duplicates.